# change struct in method

Tags: c#, .net

How can I change struct in external method ?

```
public void ChangeStruct (MyStruct myStruct) {
   myStruct.field1 = 10;
   return;
}
```

When I pass struct to ChangeStruct method after that method I would like myStruct to be changed.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you're using a `struct` for this situation?

Comment: Pretty please, don't create mutable `struct`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the struct instead of a copy using the [`ref` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) :

```
public void ChangeStruct (ref MyStruct myStruct)
{
   myStruct.field1 = 10;
}

ChangeStruct(ref someStruct);
```

Your current code create a full bit-for-bit copy of the struct before entering the method and it's this copy that you are modifying, the ref keyword force the caller to pass a reference (managed pointer) to the structure instead of the copy.

Comment: I was persuaded that this question had already been asked, but can't find the duplicate. Anyway the answer is simple...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ref` keyword to observe changes to structs, but in the grand scheme, you will be in a world of less hurt if you simply use a class.

For an idea on when to use or not use structs, you might [consult this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx). A quick snippet that you may find helpful:

> **Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following characteristics:**
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
>     (integer, double, and so on).
> - It has an instance size smaller than 16
>     bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Structs are value types, you must use the ref keyword to prevent copying. Using ref and out is not recommended, see [When is using the C# ref keyword ever a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539252/when-is-using-the-c-sharp-ref-keyword-ever-a-good-idea).