# how to replace values in list in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list:

```
List<string> strlist=new List<string>();
strlist.add("UK");
strlist.add("US");
strlist.add("India");
strlist.add("Australia");
```

I want to change the index of some elements in the list:

The current index of "US" is 1, I want to replace it with 3 and for "Australia" it should be 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function for swapping 2 elements in an array doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500312/function-for-swapping-2-elements-in-an-array-doesnt-work)

Comment: So you want the list in the order `UK, Australia, India, US`, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the indices already, you can just use 'swap' them:

```
var temp = strlist[1];
strlist[1] = strlist[3];
strlist[3] = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you really just want to sort the list.

If so, just do this:

```
strlist.Sort().
```

This will work for a plain list of strings, because `string` defines a suitable comparison operator that `Sort()` can use.

If you want to keep "UK" at the start of the list and sort the rest of the list, you can do so like this:

```
strlist.Sort(1, strlist.Count-1, null);
```

The above line will result in the list being:

```
UK
Australia
India
US
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use a swapping variable

```
String app = strlist[1];
strlist[1] = strlist[3];
strlist[3] = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<string>` can be indexed using `list[index] = ...`. That if you want to replace items manually. Otherwise (I'm guessing), if you need to sort the list alphabetically, but leave the "UK" at the top then you need to do sorting:

```
var list = new List<string> {"UK", "US", "India", "Australia" };
list.Sort((a, b) =>
{
    if (a == "UK")
        return -1;

    if (b == "UK")
        return 1;

    return string.Compare(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
});
```